# Music themed Cryptic Clues

Tags: music, cryptic-clues

Continuing a series, here are some cryptic clues which all clue to songs, pieces of music, or composers. Solve them!

> Take out middle of set for German (4)
>
> Prelude from the sky? (8)
>
> It's on the piano if Euler's angry (3,5)
>
> Animal pack is an Austrian first (8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### HERE WE GO

Take out middle of set for German (4)

> **Bach** (*batch* minus its middle piece)

Prelude from the sky? (8)

> **Raindrop Prelude**

It's on the piano if Euler's angry (3,5)

> **Für Elise** (anagram of *if Euler's* —thanks to @Hugh Meyers once again)

Animal pack is an Austrian first (8)

> **Wolfgang** (wolf gang, first name of Austrian (or, really, Salzburger (Salzburgisch?)) composer Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart)

Comment: Wild guessing: maybe 1 is from `ongpu`?

Comment: @ffao oh, you may be on to something - I was trying to figure out how to work with [that name]

Comment: 3 is an anagram of Für Elise

Comment: @HughMeyers oh my god not again

Comment: So how does `angry` fit?

Comment: I knew the answer for 3 was going to be that, but didn't think to use the 's *facepalms*

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I think `angry` is the word indicating an anagram.

Comment: @f"  I was worried about that.  Meh :/

Comment: @f'' is it just because it has `a n g r` in it?

Comment: Perhaps a long shot but Chopin's 15th Prelude is known as Raindrop (Db Major)

Comment: @question_asker Honestly, I don't know the slightest about what can clue an anagram, but there doesn't seem to be anything else to do it.

Comment: I think angry as in "the sky is angry" meaning turbulent. And the more I think about it, the more I think the prelude from the sky is Chopin's 15th, the Raindrop Prelude

Comment: I've definitely seen "angry" before as an anagram hint. Sort of like "riled up" or "furious" can mean turbulent.

Comment: Got it. BTW, the second clue was for the "Raindrop" prelude.